# Has any other work of ONE been animated aside One Punch Man and Mob Psycho 001?

Tags: one-punch-man, mob-psycho-100

One has written several stories , the best known ones probably are One Punch Man and Mob Psycho 001. These last 2 have been animated. How about the other ones? Has any other work of ONE been animated aside One Punch Man and Mob Psycho 001?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only *One Punch Man* and *Mob Psycho* [has been animated so far](https://myanimelist.net/people/16993/ONE), although [some of his works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(manga_artist)) were published as a manga by different publishers.